# Fear of becoming gay

Tags: halal-haram, homosexuality, pornography

I am a muslim teenager boy who abstained from porn and looking at women so much that my testosterone levels are now way lower than before. Waswas comes and starts giving me feelings that's I'm gay or that I should become gay. Sometimes he makes me think I should watch porn to regain love for women. But I don't want to watch porn and I don't want to do anything haram. I don't want to be gay neither. I can't marry because I'm still a minor.
MY QUESTION IS: What do I do to regain love for women without doing anything haram?

Comment: Why did my question deserve 2 downvotes? I need help

Comment: Why watching porn is haram? In some muslim countries, watching porn for educational purpose is not haram. Just don't stare too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no expert, however, my recommendation is that if you are at an age that you are struggling to find someone that you love, you should ask your parents to help you find someone that you are happy with. Ask your parents to help find someone suitable, as that's tradition. Also, Allah is fully aware that every single person has and will commit some amount of Zina. This is proven by this section in the hadith:

Abu Huraira reported Allah's Apostle as saying: “Allah has decreed for every son of Adam his share of Zina, which he will inevitably commit. The Zina of the eyes is looking, the Zina of the tongue is speaking, one may wish and desire, and the private parts confirm that or deny it.”

Trust your parent's decision is the best advice I can give you. Please note that I am not an expert, and I recommend seeing an Imam if there are other problems.

Comment: What do you really mean by "Allah is fully aware that every single person has and will commit some amount of Zina.". Does that mean 'I'm gonna have to commit Zina' or 'itdoesn't matter if I try to get away from it I will still commit it?'. Also, thanks for the answer.

Comment: From what I interpret it as, yes. He knows and has destined you to commit at least a little bit of zina. What you do determines if you are found guilty, I.E if you do not repent, E.T.C .